# Passing multiple objects with perspective broker (complex types)

Tags: python, twisted, perspective-broker

Whenever i try to pass an object (aClass) with a property with a second object (bClass) Am getting:

**Unpersistable('Unpersistable data: instance of class amodule.bClass deemed insecure')**

The aClass is copyable and unjellied, the bClass is not.

Here's my code:

server.py:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.spread import pb
from amodule import PBServer

application = service.Application("Test app")

# Prepare managers
clientManager = internet.TCPServer(8282, pb.PBServerFactory(PBServer()));
clientManager.setServiceParent(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Run with twistd"
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)
```

amodule.py:

```
from twisted.spread import pb

class bClass:
    """This is not a Copyable class
    """

class aClass(pb.RemoteCopy, pb.Copyable):
    b = bClass()
pb.setUnjellyableForClass(aClass, aClass)

class PBServer(pb.Root):
    def remote_echo(self, a):
        return a.b
```

Is there anyway to unjelly aClass and all the objects it can contain ? because unjellying included object is a headache and may turn into dirty code ...

Answer (score 2):

Use should use [setUnjellyableForClass](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.spread.jelly.setUnjellyableForClass.html):

```
setUnjellyableForClass(bClass, bClass)
```

and let bClass inherit from Copyable.

Have a look at [Passing Complex Types](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-copyable.html)